# Parsing out JSON column Array data in Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, unnest

I have some data like this

```
Product Siz Color     RFIDs
GO1199  5XL WHIT    "[\"300ED89F335000B333B8CA8D\",\"300ED89F335000B333B8C5F3\",\"E2009A4050026AF000001928\"]"
GO1189  LAR WHIT    "[\"300ED89F335000B333B8CA8D\",\"300ED89F335000B333B8C5F3\",\"E2009A4050026AF000001928\"]"
GO1179  LAR WHIT    "[\"300ED89F335000B333B8CA76\",\"300ED89F335000B333B8C7C8\",\"300ED89F335000B333B8C58D\"]",
GO1169  LAR WHIT    "[\"300ED89F335000999A72D381\",\"300ED89F3350007FC4FDCCFB\",\"300ED89F3350007FC4FDDEF9\"]",
GO1199  LAR WHIT    "[\"300ED89F3350007FC4FDDF5E\",\"300ED89F3350007FC4FDDDE1\",\"300ED89F3350007FC4FDDDDF\"]"
```

The last column is array of RFID's associated wit that product. I want prase it out and display it like so using SQL

```
Product Siz Color     RFID
GO1199  5XL WHIT    300ED89F335000B333B8CA8D
GO1199  5XL WHIT    300ED89F335000B333B8C5F3
GO1199  5XL WHIT    E2009A4050026AF000001928
GO1189  LAR WHIT    300ED89F335000B333B8CA8D
GO1189  LAR WHIT    300ED89F335000B333B8C5F3
GO1189  LAR WHIT    E2009A4050026AF000001928
```

Thanks.

Sorry this is in 5.7 not 8

Comment: Is count of array element is constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, use `json_table()`:

```
select t.product, t.size, t.color, x.rfid
from mytable t
cross join json_table(t.rfids, '$[*]' columns (rfid varchar(50) path '$')) x
```

In earlier versions, it is a bit more complicated. Basically you need a table of numbers to unnest the arrays:

```
select t.product, t.size, t.color, 
    json_unquote(json_extract(t.rfids, concat('$[', n.i, ']'))) rfid
from mytable t
inner join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2) n
    on n.i < json_length(t.rfids)
```

You can expand the subquery with more numbers to handle more than 3 items per array.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed10064740f788f98ec095f241261fcb)**:

```
product | size | color | rfid                    
:------ | :--- | :---- | :-----------------------
GO1199  | 5XL  | WHIT  | E2009A4050026AF000001928
GO1199  | 5XL  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8C5F3
GO1199  | 5XL  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8CA8D
GO1189  | LAR  | WHIT  | E2009A4050026AF000001928
GO1189  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8C5F3
GO1189  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8CA8D
GO1179  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8C58D
GO1179  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8C7C8
GO1179  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000B333B8CA76
GO1169  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F3350007FC4FDDEF9
GO1169  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F3350007FC4FDCCFB
GO1169  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F335000999A72D381
GO1199  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F3350007FC4FDDDDF
GO1199  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F3350007FC4FDDDE1
GO1199  | LAR  | WHIT  | 300ED89F3350007FC4FDDF5E
```

Comment: Sorry, this is in 5.7, not in 8.0.

Comment: @user618886: yes... I started answering before you edited your question. See my edit now.

Comment: I have the luxury of upgrading my instance to 8, so I will move to 8 and use your solution there.  Thanks for such a quick turn around.